# Equivalent of SharedWorker Port in ServiceWorker?

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker, service-worker

`SharedWorker` uses Message Port to exchange messages with `ParentWorker`.

### ParentWorker

```
var port = new SharedWorker('/worker.js').port;
port.onmessage = function(e){
    console.log(e.data);
};
port.start();
port.postMessage("Hello Shared Worker. I'm Mr. Tab");
```

### SharedWorker (worker.js)

```
onconnect = function(e){
    var port = e.ports[0];
    port.onmessage = function(e){
        console.log(e.data);
    };
    port.start();
    port.postMessage("Hello Mr. Tab. I'm Shared Worker.");
};
```

What about Service Worker? Is there anything similar to `SharedWorker` Port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jaffa The Cake's answer is just a simple in and out messaging channel, not an exact equivalent of `SharedWorker` Port. At this time, **there is no built-in interface which is similar to `SharedWorker` Port in `ServiceWorker`.** Message Channel API is mandatory. Here is the one.

### yourapp.js

```
var mc = new MessageChannel();
mc.port1.onmessage = function(e){
    console.log(e.data);
};
var sw = navigator.serviceWorker;
sw.register('/sw.js',{scope : '/'}).then(function(){
    console.log("Service Worker is successfully registered.");
}).catch(function(er){
    console.log("Registration failed.");
});
sw.ready.then(function(reg){
    reg.active.postMessage('',[mc.port2]); //initialise the messaging channel
    mc.port1.postMessage("Hello Service Worker. I'm Mr. Tab.");
});
```

### sw.js

```
//equals to onconnect in Shared Worker
onmessage = function(e){
    var port = e.ports[0];
    port.onmessage = function(e){
        console.log(e.data);
    };
    port.postMessage("Hello Mr. Tab. I'm Service Worker.");
};
```

*Note: This code is tested on Chrome 43 Beta.*

Answer (score 3):

Here's how it behaves:

```
// in the page:
navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage("Hi!");

// in the ServiceWorker:
self.onmessage = function(event) {
  event.source; // instance of Client
  event.data; // "Hi!"
  // reply
  event.source.postMessage("Hey!");
};

// back in the page:
navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage = function(event) {
  event.source; // instance of ServiceWorker
  event.data; // "Hey!"
};
```

At time of writing, Chrome currently sends postmessages from ServiceWorker to Window to window.onmessage, based on an earlier spec. Also, event.source is null.

If you need a solution in the mean time, pass in your own MessageChannel. See demo at https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/demos/postMessage/

Comment: Please note that Channel Messaging API has already been closed on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

By inspecting the `ServiceWorker.prototype` it appears that you can use `myWorker.postMessage` method and but seemingly no `myWorker.onmessage` event from window side. See also https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/ which documents this.

You can use `self.onmessage` event (http://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#service-worker-global-scope and https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/) but seemingly no `self.postMessage` method from worker side.

So currently it seems you can send messages to Service Worker, but you cannot do the reverse. Considering that `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope` inherits from `WorkerGlobalScope` in http://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/ you kind of should be able, but this is not explicitly mentioned in the documents I have found. Considering the document at https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/ it now inherits from `EventTarget` instead at least in Chrome browser.

As a suggestion, maybe the reverse communication can be awkwardly achieved by sending polling web requests that the service worker would serve in special manner as cache hits.

Comment: ServiceWorker Constructor is currently non-standard. Chrome will throw the `Illegal Constructor` error if you initialise it.

Comment: @Tresdin Yes, you cannot construct service workers yourself. It seems like you can do http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-service-workers-20140508/#navigator-service-worker-register and then `whenReady()`

Comment: I would recommend the editor's draft over the public working draft because this is what we are tracking in blink. https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/ There the ServiceWorker inherits from EventTarget and implement AbstractWorker. Also, terminate should not work.